# SQL Retrieve latest value relative to a subset

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, window-functions

I'm trying to run a SQL query that pulls in latest result relative to a subset.

GIVEN Device 1 is linked to Device 3, I would like the query to show Device 1's color as Device 3's because Device 1 is linked to Device 3 and Device 3's color has been changed most recently.

Current results:

```
Device | Color
-------+---------
   1   |  red 
   2   |  blue 
   3   |  green
```

What I would like:

```
Device | Color
-------+---------
   1   |  GREEN 
   2   |  blue 
   3   |  GREEN
```

**DeviceTable**

```
account_id
----------
   1  
   2   
   3
```

**BeaconsTable**

```
 account_id | Color  | Time 
 -----------+--------+--------
     1      | red    |  6:00
     2      | blue   |  7:00
     3      | red    |  8:00
     3      | green  | 10:00
```

**LinkTable**

```
 account_id | Link
------------+--------
     1      |   3
     2      |   - 
     3      |   -
```

Here's what I am doing right now and again, this results in the latest color for the device, but not for the linked device.

```
SELECT d.* , b.*
FROM Device d
JOIN Beacons b ON d.account_id = b.account_id  
JOIN (
    SELECT b.account_id, 
        MAX(b.timestamp) as max_date
    FROM Beacons b
    GROUP BY b.account_id) x ON x.account_id = d.account_id
    AND x.max_date = b.timestamp
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using ? Please tag it

Comment: Sqlite just added

Comment: You only talked about the color to be overwritten by the linked id but what about `timestamp` column or any column ?

Comment: What if Device 3 is linked to Device 5 and Device 5's color has been changed most recently? What results would you want in this case?

Comment: If Device 3 is linked to device 5, it should show Device 5 color. HOWEVER if device 1 is NOT linked to device 5, it should still only show latest color device 3 set.

Answer (score 0):

If I am following this logic correctly, you want to join to the links and use the `link` there, under some circumstances:

```
SELECT COALESCE(l.link, d.account_id) as device, b.color
FROM Device d LEFT JOIN
     Links l
     ON d.account_id = l.account_id LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT b.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY b.account_id ORDER BY b.time DESC) as seqnum
      FROM beacons b
     ) b
     ON b.account_id = COALESCE(l.link, d.account_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Join the tables and then `LEFT` join 1 more copy of Beacons to get the potential color of the linked device.
Then use window function `FIRST_VALUE()` to get that color:

```
select distinct d.account_id, 
       first_value(coalesce(b2.Color, b.Color)) over (partition by d.account_id order by coalesce(b2.Time, b.Time) desc) Color
from Device d
inner join Beacons b on b.account_id = d.account_id
inner join Link l on l.account_id = d.account_id
left join Beacons b2 on b2.account_id = l.Link and b2.Time > b.Time
```

note that the column `Time` must be in the format `hh:mm` so it is comparable.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=5e44d8fd08d60ac1b628b5f6944ddf1b).
Results:

```
> account_id | Color
> ---------: | :----
>          1 | green
>          2 | blue 
>          3 | green
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT
  account_id,
  color
FROM Device AS d
JOIN (
  SELECT 
    linked_id AS account_id,
    color,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY linked_id ORDER BY Time DESC) AS row_number
  FROM Beacons AS b
  JOIN (
    SELECT 
      account_id AS linked_id,
      Link AS account_id 
    FROM Linked
    ) USING (account_id)
) USING (account_id) 
WHERE row_number = 1
;
```

Here's a [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=d48e0d7126d981930663a9bd773ee0fa)